# How to automate the deployment of microservices on pivotal cloud foundry once it is build using the maven

Tags: spring, spring-boot, deployment, maven-2, cloud-foundry

I have built a micro-service using Springboot 2 and Spring 5. I can build using Maven and successfully run my springboot application. I can even do a manual push to pivotal cloud foundry using the cf commands. However, I would like to automate this process. Like whenever my maven build is successful, automation process should read my manifest file and deploy the jar from target folder to the cloud foundry environment. I'm not getting any idea on achieving it. Should I configure my settings.xml file inside the maven->.m2 repository with connection to cloud foundry to push the artifect or write some maven and cf scripts to automate it.

Please assist to advise and provide me any reference material or link to automate this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Pivotal produce both maven and gradle plugins that allow you to `cf push` your application.

For maven, you can add and configure the plugin as follows:

```
<project …>
    …
    <build>
        <plugins>
        …
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
                <artifactId>cf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>pivotal-cloud-foundry</server>
                    <target>https://api.run.pivotal.io</target>
                    <space>development</space>
                    <appname>my-java-app</appname>
                    <url>my-java-app.cfapps.io</url>
                    <memory>512</memory>
                    <instances>3</instances>

                    <env>
                        <greeting>Hello</greeting>
                    </env>

                    <services>
                        <service>
                            <name>app-db</name>
                            <label>elephantsql</label>
                            <provider>elephantsql</provider>
                            <version>n/a</version>
                            <plan>turtle</plan>
                        </service>
                    </services>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    <build>
<project>
```

This will then allow you to:

```
mvn clean package cf:push cf:start
```

HTH

Comment: this is not in their github repository any longer so is probably not supported anymore. using the `exec` plugin and just calling `cf push` would probably be more reliable and easier to support.